# dropdown is not working with day , month and year

Tags: php, html, date, drop-down-menu

```
<?php   
        $month = array();
        for ( $i=1; $i<13; $i++ ) {
        $month = date('m', mktime(0,0,0,$i,2,2000));
        $sel = ( $i == date('n') ? ' selected="selected"' : '');
        $options1[] = "<option  value=\"{$month}\" {$sel}>{$month}</option>";
}
        $options_list1 = join("", $options1);
        echo "<select name=\"month\" >{$options_list1}</select>";
        for ( $j=1; $j<32; $j++ ) {
        $theday = date('d', mktime(0,0,0,0,$j,2000));
        $sel = ( $j == date('d') ? ' selected="selected"' : '');
        $options2[] = "<option  value=\"{$theday}\" {$sel}>{$theday}</option>";
}
        $options_list2 = join("\r\n", $options2);
        echo "<select name=\"day\" >{$options_list2}</select>";
        for ( $k=1960; $k<2016; $k++ ) {
        $theyear = date('Y', mktime(0,0,0,0,2,$k));
        $sel1 = ( $k == date('Y') ? ' selected="selected"' : '');
        $options3[] = "<option  value=\"{$theyear}\" {$sel1}>{$theyear}</option>";
}
        $options_list3 = join("\r\n", $options3);
        echo "<select name=\"day\" >{$options_list3}</select>";
?>
```

its a dropdown for day , month and year . Day and month are working fine but year is not , In year my loop is not working properly and today the year is 2013 and it is selecting 2012 . can any one help me in this ?

Comment: it works in phpfiddle.org: http://phpfiddle.org/api/run/vi6-yd8

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the previous year because you're not passing the proper parameter to mktime. As the [docs state for the month parameter](https://www.php.net/mktime):

> The number of the month relative to the end of the previous year.
> Values 1 to 12 reference the normal calendar months of the year in
> question. **Values less than 1 (including negative values) reference the
> months in the previous year in reverse order, so 0 is December**, -1 is
> November, etc. Values greater than 12 reference the appropriate month
> in the following year(s).

So change:

```
$theyear = date('Y', mktime(0,0,0,0,2,$k));
```

to

```
$theyear = date('Y', mktime(0,0,0,1,2,$k));
```

and you're fine.

**[codepad example](http://codepad.org/ovilnDC2)**